# Visual Web Designer - filtering a form view

Tags: sql, visual-web-developer-2010

Firstly, apologies for asking what is probably a basic question but I have only every been a dabbler in coding. I am trying to setup a very simple database that will save a lot of time for our users. The SQL side I am fine with, it is designing webpages that they can use to enter data that is the problem.

As I say, it is a very simple system. We have 30 odd sites that each have their own sales targets. These are currently entered into spreadsheets which are manually collated by a lady which takes for ever. Once I can get the data into SQL, I know I can automate all of what she currently does and get management reports very easily.

I currently have 3 tables - one for sales figures, one for targets and one for sites. The site table is just SiteID and SiteName. The targets table just has a site ID, date and target and the sales has site ID, date, sales, calls and referrals. As the sites will enter their own data and won't see anyone else's, I have managed to setup a webpage that lets them edit their figures using Gridview and this works fine.

Where I am hitting issues is with the targets database. I want just one web page that allows updating all sites targets. Whilst I could set up a simple page that shows all sites targets, this would be very unwieldy. What I want is a drop down list that shows the site names and feeds the site number from this into a Form View so the Form View only shows the targets for the selected site. Easy enough in SSRS with a parameter and this is what I am used to but I can't figure out how to effectively pass a selection from one object to another. That is what I essentially want - the equivalent of a table selected parameter.

Is there an easy way to do this or is it more complex than I am imagining it should be?

Many thanks,

Edit - just to clarify. I have a drop down list called DropDownList1 which has the text set to site.sitename and value set to site.siteno. What I want is for the select command of my form view to have similar to the following - WHERE site.siteno = DropDownList1.value

I get DropDownList1.Value could not be bound but this is the sort of way I envisage doing it.

Edit 2

Actually, by hacking around and entering random search terms, I think I have cracked it. ControlParameter was my friend!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, by hacking around and entering random search terms, I think I have cracked it. ControlParameter was my friend!